# I gave 12 weeks notice but want to leave before the final week

Tags: united-states, notice-period, resignation

I gave my employer 12 weeks notice (instead of the normal notice they request of 2 weeks). However, I am not doing much and want to leave before the 12 weeks is over.

Am I at risk for any penalty?

Comment: Where in the world are you? Do you have an employment contract?

Comment: i am in the united states

Comment: This answer will vary depending on what state your in.

Answer (score 4):

This is company specific.

If you wish to terminate your employment before your notice is up, talk to HR and see what you can work out with them. Leaving early without doing so can burn the bridge and prevent you from coming back to this company if you ever need to. Additionally, even though most jurisdictions forbid it, hiring managers talk, and you may find it harder to find a job in the future if you get a reputation for not serving your notice period.

In the future, I would recommend not giving more than the required notice, barring special relationships with your boss or other similar circumstances.

Note: In general, if you served a long notice, and the company kept you on (as opposed to informing you that the notice period is not required and letting you go immediately) It means they expect that they will need you during that notice period. If you're lacking things to do, discuss that with your manager.

Comment: I gave the long notice because it will take a while to get a replacement. They finally got a replacement, that is why I feel i am not needed anymore

Comment: i discussed with the manager and he asked me to write another resignation letter stating I will need to leave earlier. I am suspicious that he wants to use that to penalize me, because then it will be like I gave less than the required 2 weeks notice.

Comment: Append the original letter to the new one, and reference it in the new one. That way it's clear that you served more than the minimum required notice.

Comment: Or refer to the old one - ie "I am writing to request amendment of the notice period given in the letter dated X from 12 weeks to 10 weeks making my new final date Y". That way there is absolutely no way they can even selectively quote you to imply you offered less than the minimum notice period. Also I feel that once a notice period has been agreed that it is unprofessional to just state a new one rather than requesting one. Whatever you may feel they may have plans that require your full notice (even if that is just wanting you there to support your replacement).

Comment: I agree with the comment by GOATNine and @Chris. This provides both you and the company the best of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

If two weeks notice is required, then you can give two weeks notice at any time. For example after nine weeks of your original notice.